# Is there a Form Builder for Java/Spring web apps?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I'm migrating from `PHP` to `Java` and `Spring`. I noticed that `Spring`, even if it's great framework, misses things that are bundled in other frameworks on other platforms. One that I miss most is ability to build form using dedicated builders, without writing single line of `html`.

[Let's take `Symfony2` for example (click here for full article):](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

```
/**
 * Controller class
 */ 
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Post'))
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Having this code, all I have to do is to call `form` (in fact form's `toString()` method, but appropriate `twig` plugin handles that) in my view. HTML is generated and filled on the fly:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

[image: rendered form, image taken from symfony site]

Validation is done on entity (single field and complex validators), but you can also attach validators to form itself.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality in `Spring`?

Comment: Hey, I was wondering the same thing. Did you find a similar solution to symfony's form component? By the way (if you don't know), there is a port of Twig for Java called [jTwig](http://jtwig.org/) if you're used to it.